# Некорректный результат умножения матриц или логическая ошибка?

Tags: c++, python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Доброго времени суток! Решил для себя заняться нейросетями. Прочитал книгу Тарика Рашида "Make Your Own Neural Network", там в конце есть пример реализации трёхслойного перцептрона для классификации рукописных цифр с использованием матриц.

Если кратко, то при таком подходе выход слоя нейронной сети - это произведение матриц весов связей с предыдущим слоем на матрицу входов этого слоя. В матрице диапазон значений от нуля до единицы, а в матрице весов от нуля до примерно 0.03571428571 (размер слоя ^ -0.5).

Интереса ради решил переписать реализацию из книги на C++ с использованием Boost. В реализации на C++ сигнал всех нейронов выходного слоя (что является, по сути, вероятностью принадлежности к какому-либо классу) почему-то равен 1.0, получается что то, что подали на вход на 100% относится ко всем классам, чего быть не может. Затем переписал с Python на C++ с Eigen, который используется в TensorFlow, то же самое. Переписал на Go + Gonum, то же самое.

Первое расхождение уже после первого умножения матриц: умножения матрицы весов связей входного слоя со скрытым. В результате получается матрица со значениями типа 3.27362482790, 5.4859804, 6.4859834 и т.д. Но как такое возможно, если максимальные значения в умножаемых матрицах не превышают единицы?
Ссылки на реализации:

- C++: https://gist.github.com/nickfromXXII/09837f2c2953f2414d84fda65a4ffe9f
- Python: https://github.com/makeyourownneuralnetwork/makeyourownneuralnetwork/blob/master/part2_neural_network_mnist_data.ipynb

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста входные данные для нейросети и выводы по каждому из слоёв, которые у вас получлись.

Comment: В перемножении матриц используется не только умножение, но и сложение, отсюда и числа больше 1.

Comment: Возможно проблемы из-за различных функций активации нейронов, к примеру

Comment: Если ваш код маленький и обозримый, приложите его прямо в вопрос. Если ваш код большой и/или необозримый, уменьшите его до минимального воспроизводящего примера, и приложите прямо в вопрос.

Comment: Персептрон в задачах распознавания всегда имеет сигмоидальную функцию активации (после каждого произведения матриц - во всех нейронах), как уже говорилось в комментариях. А для обратного распространения ошибки нужно брать производную этой функции.